# Elasticsearch Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapper for somefield conflicts with existing mapping in other types

Tags: elasticsearch, exception, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

This exception comes when we try to insert into elasticsearch , and we have different template for mapping

mapper somefield has different [norms] values, cannot change from disable to enabled]

Answer (score 0):

Just found answer to questions.I tried When there is date change or new index is created this happens.

```
 "norms" : false
```

does the trick and you wont get this error .This is related to scoring

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/norms.html